# Model not user specific

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Post. The data in Post is displayed to every user while I want this to be user specific.

I'm new to Django. This app is created following the Django for Girls tutorial. I later added support for user registration.

models.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Example from views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

@login_required
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Example from the template (post_list.html):

```
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your filter to filter by user as well as published_date:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    published_date__lte=timezone.now(),
    author=request.user
).order_by('published_date')
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your class/function view check if the user is authenticated.

```py
if not request.user.is_superuser:
    raise Http404
```

[Also check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.is_authenticated)